# Stack.pop memory management

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, clr, managed-c++

```
Stack^ my_stack=gcnew Stack;
my_class^ a=gcnew my_class;
my_stack->Push(a);
my_stack->Push(gcnew my_class);
my_stack->Pop(); //will it cause memory leak?
a=gcnew my_class;
my_stack->Pop(); //will it cause memory leak?
```

sorry that the code is not tested. But I guess you all get what I mean here.
when you pop a pointer, you lose the pointer; will the memory be released?
there is also a method `my_stack->Clear()` which is also confusing for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

**edit:**

@Konrad Rudolph

Would the Pop() method call the destructor itself or the clr will automatically retrieve the memory space?

Konrad Rudolph also suggests me to consider using generic collection classes only.

For the new `System::Collections::Generic::Stack<T>`
It says 'Removes and returns the object at the top of the Stack'
And if so, what if I have another pointer pointed to object before?
that is,

```
my_class^ a=gcnew my_class;
Stack<my_class>^ my_stack=gcnew Stack<my_class>;
my_stack->Push(a);
my_stack->Pop(); //what is a now? nullptr?
```

Comment: Why do you even put raw pointers in your container in the first place?

Comment: it works that way...check here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.push.aspx)

Comment: @Immueggpain Whatever else, consider using generic collection classes only. The non-generic ones (from `System::Collections`) are, for all intents and purposes, deprecated and should not be used. Use [`System::Collections::Generic::Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph thanks for your help. And what's the difference between generic collection classes and non-generic collection classes? I also see here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9say334k.aspx). It says 'Removes and returns the object at the top of the Stack<T>'. If so, what if I have another pointer pointed to object before? Does the pointer become a nullptr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pop does not call the destructor. You can use something like

```
T *topObject = my_stack->top();
my_stack->pop();
delete topObject;
```